# Remove columns in dgrid dynamically

Tags: dojo, dgrid

I am creating a dgrid using columnHider. I was able to hide/show columns using `this.dgridTable.toggleColumnHiddenState(columnId, hidden);`

However, I want to altogether remove specific columns from view(including the column hider menu). Is there a way to do this without re-creating the grid with a new set of columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use `this.dgridTable.set('columns', newColumnsDescription);`. It does update the column hider menu as well.

You will have to build newColumnsDescription to reflect the addition / removal of columns as per your needs.

Comment: The editor in my columns does not seem to work after using dgridTable.set method. Is there a workaround, to attach the edit events ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean with "edit events". I just provide the editor, editOn, editorArgs, canEdit column definition properties for each column in newColumnsDescription.